# Creating a git repository to upload joomla local site

Tags: git, joomla

Im new to git and have been tasked to create a repository of the joomla site that I have been working on my local laptop so we can collaborate with other workmates.

Where do I start or anyone with a clear cut procedure of how I should go about it

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some information for you to start using git and github:

- **Working with git and github**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Working_with_git_and_github
- **Git for Coders**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Git_for_Coders
- **Git for Testers and Trackers**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Git_for_Testers_and_Trackers
- **Git branching quickstart**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Git_branching_quickstart
- **Using the Github UI to Make Pull Requests**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_Github_UI_to_Make_Pull_Requests/en
- **Git and github basics**
  http://phproberto.com/es/32-git-github-basic-workflow

Regards.